# ForEach loop inside a button action in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I understand that a ForEach loop is typically used to display a view. When I put a ForEach loop inside the action button it pretty much tells me Button action cannot conform to the view protocol. So how can I use a loop to make the button carry out multiple actions?

```
struct SomeView: View {
    var newExercises = [NewExercise]()
    var finalExercises = [Exercise]()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            ForEach(newExercises) { newExercise in
                //.getExercise() returns an Exercise object
                finalExercises.append(newExercise.getExercise())
            }

        }) {
            Text("Done")
        }
    }
}
```

I want the button to add an Exercise (by calling .getExercise()) to the finalExercises array for each newExercise in the newExercises array.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `SwiftUI` `ForEach` statement returns a `View` for each `Element` of an `Array`.  For your code, you simply need to run a `Void`, `Array<Exercise>.append(newElement: Exercise)` not get multiple `View`'s, so you can use a `for` loop, `map`, or `Array.forEach(body: (_) throws -> Void)`.

If the order in which the `newExercises` are appended matters, the most elegant solution will be mapping each `NewExercise` of `finalExercises` to a `Exercise`, and appending the resulting `Array<Exercise>`, with `Array<Exercise>.append(contentsOf: Sequence)`.

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var newExercises = [NewExercise]()
    @State var finalExercises = [Exercise]()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.finalExercises.append(contentsOf:
                self.newExercises.map { newExercise -> Exercise in
                    newExercise.getExercise()
                }
            )


        }) {
            Text("Done")
        }
    }
}
```

If the order in which the `newExercises` are appended does not matter, you can call `Array<Exercise>.append(newElement: Exercise)` from `newExcercises.forEach`, which is different than a `SwiftUI` `ForEach` statement:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var newExercises = [NewExercise]()
    @State var finalExercises = [Exercise]()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.newExercises.forEach { newExercise in
                self.finalExercises.append(newExercise.getExercise())
            }
        }) {
            Text("Done")
        }
    }
}
```

The way to complete what you want with a for loop would be simple, but less elegant:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State var newExercises = [NewExercise]()
    @State var finalExercises = [Exercise]()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            for newExercise in self.newExercises {
                self.finalExercises.append(newExercise.getExercise())
            }

        }) {
            Text("Done")
        }
    }
}
```